# UIPopoverController: dealloc reached while popover is still visible

Tags: ios, ipad, uipopovercontroller, popover

I am working on an app that lets the user select images from his own photo album. It works on iPhone, but not on  iPad.

I made  a `UIPopoverController`, and it all works fine, the user can pick a photo, but when the user pushes "USE" button. the app cashes a says

> UIPopoverController dealloc] reached while popover is still visible

here is the code:

```
- (void)choosePhotoFromLibraryipad:(id)sender{


    if(![popoverController isPopoverVisible]){


    imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;

    self.popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:imagePicker];

    [self.popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 400.0, 400.0)
    inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES ];

    }
}
```

Comment: have you written `[popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];` when you want to hide popover? And please specify that you are using `ARC` or not?

Comment: YES i have forgotten to make a [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES]; 
embarrassing :-D after so many hours, its was that easy

Answer (score 5):

Check your `.h` file. Make sure that your `@property` for your `popoverController` is **`strong` instead of `weak`**. Many an hour of time has been wasted over simple things like this.

Comment: I have forgotten to make a [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES] but thanks for your answer.